# VLC player not current version

Tags: software-center, vlc

I just downloaded VLC from the software center in Ubuntu.  But, it is not the current version.  It is version 2.1.6.

Is it safe to use this version?

Why isn't the current version available through the software center?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to use version `2.1.6` - it is a stable and trusted version.

Ubuntu repositories (which are used by Software Center) do not have the latest versions of VLC.

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/151304/338915) gives an explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to use this version?

Please be more specific on why you have doubt that the package is not safe. Using the latest version of a software doesn't automatically guarantee safety.

Most of the necessary information to judge if a package is safe to use can be found by looking at the corresponding page for the package on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vlc).

In this case you can see that the package is maintained by:

> Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers

There is also a change log with useful information:

```
vlc (2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) trusty-security; urgency=medium

  * New upstream release to fix multiple security issues (LP: #1419176)

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Wed, 25 Mar 2015 21:56:16 -0400
```

I'm not aware of any newer security vulnerability for VLC.